# Finding the PDF of $Y = X^2$ given the pdf and cdf of $X$, where $X$ is uniformly distributed

Tags: probability, random-variables

[Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT4kT.png)

In the above picture (taken from [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/readings/MIT18_05S14_Reading5d.pdf)), they use an alternative way to find the pdf using a change of variables rather than the fundamental theorem of calculus. Specifically, my question involves this part:

$$y = x ^2 \rightarrow dy = 2xdx \rightarrow dx = \frac{dy}{2 \sqrt{y}}$$

$$f_X(x) dx = \frac{dx}{2} = \frac{dy}{4 \sqrt{y}} = f_Y(y) dy$$

How do they equate $\frac{dy}{4 \sqrt{y}}$ to $f_Y(y) dy$ ? I can't figure out how they got this equality

Comment: PS: that is **Uniformly** distributed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$F_Y(y) = F_X(x)$ so $$\dfrac{\mathrm d F_Y(y)}{\mathrm d y}=\dfrac{\mathrm d F_X(x)}{\mathrm d y}$$

Apply the Chain Rule to obtain:

$$f_Y(y) = f_X(x)\dfrac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d y}$$

Now substitute $x:= +\surd y$ and $\mathrm dx := (\mathrm d y)/2\surd y$  (or rather $\tfrac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm dy}=\tfrac{\mathrm d \surd y}{\mathrm d y}=\tfrac 1{2\surd y}$ )

$$f_Y(y) = f_X(\surd y)\dfrac {1}{2\surd y}$$

---

The rest is that $f_X(x) = 1/2$ under $x\in(0..2)$  because this example is **uniformly** distributed over that support.

$$f_Y(y) = \dfrac {1}{4\surd y}\quad\big[ ~y\in(0..4)~\big]$$

Comment: Why is $F_Y(y)=F_X(x)$?

Comment: $\begin{align}F_Y(y) &= \mathsf P(Y\leqslant y) \\& = \mathsf P(X^2\leqslant y)&\quad&Y:=X^2\\& = \mathsf P(-\surd y\leqslant X\leqslant \surd y) \\& = \mathsf P(X\leqslant \surd y) &&X\in(0..2)\\& =\mathsf P(X\leqslant x)&& x=\surd y\\ & = F_X(x)\end{align}$

Comment: Of course, if $X$ could be negative (say it was distributed over $(-2..2)$), then we would have $F_Y(y) = F_X(\surd y)-F_X(-\surd y)$ and therefore $f_Y(y)= (2\surd y)^{-1}\, (f_X(\surd y)+f_X(-\surd y))$

Comment: Ah, I see why $F_Y(y) = F_X(x)$ now, thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Sorry, I had a quick follow-up question. It seems that this change-of-variable methodology can be applied to a lot of problems of this type (ex: in my question, finding $f_Y(y)$ for arbitrary $y$ by using a change of variable for $y = x^2$). Is there a theorem or something that generalizes this idea?

Comment: Yes, indeed @AdityaMehrotra , the theorem dealing with change of variables in an integral is the [Change of Variables Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChangeofVariablesTheorem.html)

Answer (score 0):

> I can't figure out how they got this equality

In your example $X\sim U(0;2)$ thus $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2}$

You arrive at

$$dx=\frac{dy}{2\sqrt{y}}$$

thus this is the same as

$$f_X(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{dy}{2\sqrt{y}}=f_Y(y)dy$$

---

but your main question is how to apply this procedure when $X$ is gaussian. Before doing the calculation, it is important to know if your gaussian is centered (gaussian with mean 0) or it is not...

Comment: Also, because a Gaussian random variable may be either positive of negative: $$f_{X^2}(y)=(2\surd y)^{-1} f_X(+\surd y)+(2\surd y)^{-1} f_X(-\surd y)$$

Comment: I'm so sorry, I accidentally wrote normally distributed in my question title, but I should've written uniform, as that was part of the question I was trying to ask

Comment: @AdityaMehrotra : sometimes a typo can be an opportunity: Try to to the same exercise with $X\sim N(0;1)$. The result is a known distribution